# Setting up a probability mass function

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we have a drawer full of 10 socks.  Exactly one of the socks is black.  You continue to draw the socks from the bowl, one at a time without replacement until the black one is drawn.  Let X be the number of trials needed to draw the black sock.

a) Find the probability that P($X\leq4$)
Based on my understanding is it organized as follows?
P(X=1)=1/10
P(X=2)=9/10*1/9
P(X=3)=9/10*8/9*1/8
P(X=4)=9/10*8/9*7/8*1/7

Since all of them equal to 1/10 would then the probability is 4/10 right?

From here how would you set up a probability mass function for X and how would this be different than the above mentioned probability of X less than or equal to 4?

Comment: You haven't said how many socks there are.

Comment: Good catch, my bad.

Comment: If there are $10$ socks, why would $P(X=1) = \frac19$?

Comment: Note that is obvious (or soon becomes obvious) *without calculation* that $\Pr(X=k)=\frac{1}{10}$ for every $k$ between $1$ and $10$. For the black sock is equally likely to be first drawn, second drawn, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The PMF is
$$P_X(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac1{10}, & x = 1, 2,\ldots,10\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The probability $P(X\le 4) = \frac4{10}$ therefore is consistent with the one calculated from the PMF:
$$P(X\le 4) = \sum_{i = -\infty}^4 P_X(x)$$

Comment: How would that be different from P$(X\leq4)$?